# How to prevent third party to seeing the data on same channel in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

So basically in Hyperledger Fabric the third party information provider have to be a part of the channel and once they become the part of the channel they get to see all the information on the channel which can be data security breach. Is there a way we can prevent them seeing the whole data but still give us the required information.
example - Market data provider for a trading system when two banks are trading each other do they need to share that trade information with the market data provider or they can just get the prices from the market data provider without sharing that trade information and Corda is achieving this through oracle so is that something similar on hyper ledger fabric.

Comment: Do you mean private data? You can try to take a [look](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private-data/private-data.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rahul Singh

You can use private data concept

Earlier it was people use to create multiple channels but now `private data concept`

one channel you can control data between members

All you have to do is create collections

Read from here

Doc: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private_data_tutorial.html

Chaincode: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/chaincode/marbles02_private

Node-sdk: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-private-data.html