# How organizations can communicate privately with each other on same channel without sharing the data in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Lets say there are 100 banks on the street, they trade each other but they also don't want to share the data with the other banks who is not the part of the transaction. so basically in that case they will have to create a dedicated channel for each possible combination, so assuming 100 banks each trading with each other 100 x 9 = 900. If i put them in same channel they will get to see the data for the transaction they are not part of, so only option i have left is to keep them on a separate channel but is there any scalability issue with having too many participants in the network. how is really going to scale in Hyperledger Fabric or How can we manage this type of use case in Hyperledger Fabric ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you duplicate the question

I have answered in your previous question

[How to prevent third party to seeing the data on same channel in Hyperledger Fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864334/how-to-prevent-third-party-to-seeing-the-data-on-same-channel-in-hyperledger-fab)

Answer (score 0):

There is one very important feature provided by the Hyper-ledger fabric for scenarios like these. Its called Private Data. A set of Organizations in a consortium can hide the data from other organizations using this feature, and avoid creating a new channel altogether.

Please see below link for detailed explanation. It has everything , including an use case which will help in understanding the practical usage of private data.

[Private Data in Hyperledger fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private-data/private-data.html)